# perform an update across many record only if all records meet a criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update a batch of rows, but only if all rows in the batch meet a criteria.

Example table:

```sql
create table thing (
    id int primary key,
    ref int
);
```

Example data:

```sql
INSERT INTO thing (id, ref)
VALUES
    (1, NULL)
    , (2, NULL)
    , (3, 1)
    , (4, 1);
```

Example bad query - this updates rows 1 and 2, but will leave row 3 as-is (undesired):

```sql
UPDATE thing
SET ref = 2
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AND ref IS NULL;
```

Goal: a single query which either 1: updates all matching rows; OR 2: does nothing and somehow inform me (eg. 0 rows updated) so can throw a warning.

edit - sample here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f9ad9/4

Comment: The application API you use to call Postgres would typically use a driver which would return the number of rows affected by the update.

Comment: it does — but by then the update is already performed, which i'm hoping to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is how i solved my own problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bccf0/1

```sql
UPDATE thing
SET ref = 2
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AND ref IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS ( -- if anything returns here — nothing will update
  SELECT 1
  FROM thing
  WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AND ref IS NOT NULL
)
RETURNING id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update all or nothing if there exists a row which  satisfies part of the `WHERE` condition but not all terms of the conjunction.

```
UPDATE thing
SET ref = 2
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AND ref IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from thing t where t.id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) and t.ref IS NOT NULL or not(t.id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3])) AND t.ref IS NULL)
```

Alternatively, case when an original conjunction in WHERE has more then two terms

```
UPDATE thing
SET ref = 2
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AND ref IS NULL
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                from thing t 
                where ( t.id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) or t.ref IS NULL)-- disjunction of terms of original conjunction
                  and ( not(t.id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) or t.ref IS NOT NULL) --disjunction of negations of terms of original conjunction
               );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5ab26ced2e78f7dd242ae2b0464a5c83)

Comment: nice! inspired by this — i think i got something working. Although it's maybe simpler than your sample — maybe you can review it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bccf0/1

Comment: What about `(1, null) , (2, null), (3, null)` ?  My query treats all conjunction terms equally it will prohibit the update because `(3, null)` satisfies one term of conjunction and doesn't satisfies the other one. Your query will allow an update.  Sure it's your bussiness to decide on which is correct for your system.

Comment: Added a fiddle and commented on the query logic.

Comment: i honestly don't know what a "conjunction" is so i can't understand your comment — but i think there's a bug in your link, see line 6 and 7 of the second query — the ANY variables differ from the first. Also it doesn't seem to meet the brief, since if i update `(3, NULL)` to `(3, 1)` it continues to update row 1 and 2, which is no better than my first SQL in the question labeled "Example bad query"

Comment: "conjunction" I mean a logical operation https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Conjunction here.

Comment: '(3,1)'  will not  prohibit the update because it violates both  `id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2]` term and  `ref IS NULL` term.  The idea was to prohibit the update when one of the terms is satisfied and the other one fails.

Answer (score 1):

- first determine the number of records in the batch and the number of records to be updated in it (the pre_condition CTE);
- update only if these numbers are the same;
- return the id-s of the updated rows as a result

```sql
with pre_condition as
(
 select
        count(*) filter (where id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3])) batch_count,
        count(*) filter (where id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AND ref IS NULL) set_count
 from thing
)

UPDATE thing
SET ref = 2
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3]) AND ref IS NULL

and (select batch_count = set_count from pre_condition)
returning id;
```